# Only one node owns data in a Cassandra cluster

Tags: configuration, cassandra

I am new to Cassandra and just run a cassandra cluster (version 1.2.8) with 5 nodes, and I have created several keyspaces and tables on there.  However, I found all data are stored in one node (in the below output, I have replaced ip addresses by node numbers manually):

```
Datacenter: 105
==========
Address         Rack        Status State   Load            Owns                Token
                                                                               4
node-1          155         Up     Normal  249.89 KB       100.00%             0
node-2          155         Up     Normal  265.39 KB       0.00%               1
node-3          155         Up     Normal  262.31 KB       0.00%               2
node-4          155         Up     Normal  98.35 KB        0.00%               3
node-5          155         Up     Normal  113.58 KB       0.00%               4
```

and in their `cassandra.yaml` files, I use all default settings except `cluster_name`, `initial_token`, `endpoint_snitch`, `listen_address`, `rpc_address`, `seeds`, and `internode_compression`.  Below I list those non-ip address fields I modified:

```
endpoint_snitch: RackInferringSnitch
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
seed_provider:
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          - seeds: "node-1, node-2"
internode_compression: none
```

and all nodes using the same seeds.

Can I know where I might do wrong in the config? And please feel free to let me know if any additional information is needed to figure out the problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are starting with Cassandra 1.2.8 you should try using the vnodes feature.  Instead of setting the `initial_token`, uncomment `# num_tokens: 256` in the cassandra.yaml, and leave `initial_token` blank, or comment it out.  Then you don't have to calculate token positions.  Each node will randomly assign itself 256 tokens, and your cluster will be mostly balanced (within a few %).  Using vnodes will also mean that you don't have to "rebalance" you cluster every time you add or remove nodes.

See this blog post for a full description of vnodes and how they work:
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/virtual-nodes-in-cassandra-1-2

Answer (score 1):

Your token assignment is the problem here. An assigned token are used determines the node's position in the ring and the range of data it stores. When you generate tokens the aim is to use up the entire range from 0 to (2^127 - 1). *Tokens aren't id's like with mysql cluster where you have to increment them sequentially*.

There is a [tool on git](https://github.com/tjake/Cassandra-Token-Calculator/blob/master/TokenCalulator.java) that can help you calculate the tokens based on the size of your cluster.

Read [this article](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/initialize/token_generation) to gain a deeper understanding of the tokens. And if you want to understand the meaning of the numbers that are generated [check this article out](http://journal.paul.querna.org/articles/2010/09/24/cassandra-token-selection/).

Answer (score -1):

You should provide a `replication_factor` when creating a keyspace:

`CREATE KEYSPACE demodb
       WITH REPLICATION = {'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 3};`

If you use `DESCRIBE KEYSPACE x` in `cqlsh` you'll see what `replication_factor` is currently set for your keyspace (I assume the answer is 1).

More details [here](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/webhelp/index.html?pagename=docs&version=1.2&file=dml/using_cli#cassandra/cql_using/create_keyspace_c.html)

Comment: But even when the replication factor is 1, should the data in one keyspace be distributed into multiple nodes?

Comment: no..for replication factor 1 no replication of data takes place within a data centre